# Angular 2 search filter works for one property but not for all properties of an array

Tags: angular, ionic-filter-bar, angular2-filtering

In Angular 1, there is filter attribute along with `ng-repeat` as mentioned [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

But in Angular 2 there is new functionality named *"pipe"*. I have used pipes already but still I can't search through all properties like in the Angular 1 version.

However it is working fine for any 1 property, but for whole array, it's not working.

I got following error when i search something.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null
>             at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:118751:76
>             at Array.some (native)
>             at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:118751:42
>             at Array.filter (native)
>             at FilterPipe.transform (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:118750:26)
>               at checkAndUpdatePureExpressionInline (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:11519:38)
>               at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12374:17)
>               at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12336:16)
>               at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12965:59)
>               at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12906:13)
>               at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/Orders.ngfactory.js:628:46)
>               at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12891:21)
>               at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12303:14)
>               at callViewAction (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12618:17)
>               at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12564:13)
>
> ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 43, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}component:
>   (...)componentRenderElement: (...)context: (...)elDef:
>   ObjectbindingFlags: 2bindingIndex: 6bindings: Array(1)childCount:
>   1childFlags: 73728childMatchedQueries: 0directChildFlags:
>   73728element: Objectflags: 1index: 42matchedQueries:
>   ObjectmatchedQueryIds: 0ngContent: nullngContentIndex: 0outputIndex:
>   3outputs: Array(0)parent: Objectprovider: nullquery: nullreferences:
>   ObjectrenderParent: Objecttext: null__proto__: ObjectelOrCompView:
>   (...)elView: Objectinjector: (...)nodeDef: ObjectnodeIndex:
>   43providerTokens: (...)references: (...)renderNode: (...)view:
>   Object__proto__: Object

Below is my code for reference:

1) FilterPipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
@Injectable()
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: any, term: any): any {
        if (term) {
            // THIS IS WORKING BUT FOR ONLY order_id PROPERTY
            // return items.filter(function (item) {
            //     return item.order_id.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
            // });

            // THIS IS NOT WORKING
            return items.filter(item => {
                return Object.keys(item).some(k => item[k].includes(term.toLowerCase()));
            });
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

2) Orders.html

```
<ion-header style="direction: ltr;">
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="logout()">
        <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-title>הזמנה</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="getOrders()">
        <ion-icon name="refresh"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="showFilterBar()">
        <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ul class="list" *ngFor="let order of orders | filter : Search.value">
    <li class="item {{order.color}}" (click)="gotoorderdetails(order)">
      <div style="float:left;">
        {{order.start_date}}<br/>
      </div>
      <b>{{order.order_id}} </b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;צ - {{order.total_staff}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ימ- {{order.number_of_days}}<br/><br/>      {{order.full_name}}
      <br/>
      <div style="float:left;">
        {{order.managers}}<br/>
      </div>
      <span *ngIf="order.event_location"> {{order.event_location}}<br/></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-searchbar #Search (keyup)="0"></ion-searchbar>
</ion-footer>
```

How can I use the [ionic filter bar](https://github.com/djett41/ionic-filter-bar) in ionic 2.

Comment: One of the properties of an object of the array is null, but you try to call includes on it. You need to check if the property is not null, not undefined, is a string, etc. That said, Angular chose not to implement a filter pipe on purpose, because it's inherently slow, especially when checking all the properties. It recommends filtering when needed, in the component.

Comment: and how to do that can you please provide final code? @JBNizet

Comment: No, that's not how it works. If you want someone to write code for you, you should hire a developer.

Comment: maybe question should asked to angular 2 community. -_-

Comment: by final code i mean you can suggest an edit in my Filter.

Comment: I already did. Check that the property is not null, not undefined, is a string, before calling includes() on it.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet. I got it working now. :).... Still ionic-filter bar is remaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) for an answer.

Below is my working updated code.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
@Injectable()
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: any, term: any): any {
        if (term) {
            return items.filter(item => {
                return Object.keys(item).some(
                    k => {
                        if (item[k] != null && item[k] != undefined && typeof item[k] == 'string')
                            return item[k].includes(term.toLowerCase());
                    }
                );
            });
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: change `return item[k].includes(term.toLowerCase());` to `return item[k].toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());` to support lower case search